# Display label depending on timedate attribute used by Temporal Controller

Tags: qgis, time, animation, temporal-controller

I have a layer with two attribute columns: *stop_name* and *schedule*. I am animating this layer using Temporal Controller, so a dot displays on the map whenever the *schedule* time is active, as seen on [this](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/animating_time_series.html) tutorial.

I would like to display the *stop_name* label whenever the relevant *schedule* attribute is active on Time Controller. I have tried, unsuccesfully, using CASE WHEN; however, I cannot figure out how to make this conditional dependant of what is displayed by the Temporal Controller.

Comment: Hello, sharing a code sample of what you have tried would be a good starting point for others to help you. Which mode of the Temporal Controller are you using ? Cases with tests on `@map_start_time` should to the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a lablel with the rule

```
@map_start_time <= "time" and "time" <= @map_end_time
```

[image]

and replace `"time"` with your datetime field.

Then set up the temporal settings of the layer to `Redraw layer only`.

[image]

Example result:

[image]

Comment: This solution works perfectly. In case it helps anyone else, using `Separate Fields for Start and End Date/Time` instead of `Redraw layer only` also works.