# Use several colours in Decorations - Title Label in QGIS

Tags: qgis, time-series, animation, temporal-controller, title

I have been trying to dynamically display labels based in the Decoration Title Label in QGIS, as can be seen on [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/448762/183135) answer by the user [Kasper](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/212971/kasper).

What I am trying to achieve now is to change the colour of those labels, somehow overriding the default colour option the Title Label provides here under the `Font` option:
[image]

Ideally, on a string as the following one, which always displays first the name of the line and then dynamically the stops as the animation moves forward: `Jubilee line: aggregate(layer:='your_layer_name',aggregate:='concatenate_unique', expression:="stop_name", filter:=@map_start_time <= "time" and "time" <= @map_end_time, concatenator:=',')` the *Jubilee Line* bit should have a different colour than the rest of the text.

I believe wrapping the title (this *Jubilee Line* bit in the example) in a `CASE WHEN ... THEN ...` and calling a `color_rgb` function might work, but I couldn't achieve anything successful yet.

Comment: You can use HTML formatting for that (I don't know enough about to give a full anwser): https://north-road.com/2022/09/09/mixed-format-labels-in-qgis-coming-soon/

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. HTML formatting is allowed almost elsewhere but not on the Title Label. Perhaps something interesting to be implemented on future QGIS updates.

Comment: I had done a quick try an had managed to have one part of static text in bold, the other part of a different colour, Title decoration , Qgis 3.28

Comment: Oh, I see. You have to enable the 'Allow HTML formatting' option inside the Font configuration dialogue. Indeed, then it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `HTML` rendering in the `Title Decoration`:

First enable it in the Font properties by ticking the appropriate box:[image]

Format the Title as needed:
[image]

It works: [image]